# Add custom button / text to dates with no event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have gone through the documentation of full calendar quite a few times but never came across to topics related to this issue. So far, I could show the text to the dates with the event, such as `already  booked`, using eventRender as follows:

```
eventRender: function(event, element){

                    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                        var eventStart = moment(event.start);
                        var eventEnd = event._end === null ? eventStart : moment(event.end);
                        var diffInDays = eventEnd.diff(eventStart, 'days');

                        $(element).css("display", "none");
                        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '"]').append("<div class='already-booked'><span>Already Booked <br></span></div>");

                },
```

However, I want to add text/button with "**Available**" on those dates which don't have any event. But, its been weeks, I could not find the solution.

So, I would appreciate any help to achieve this requirement.

To make things easier, I have created a pen on the codepen, which could be forked from [here](https://codepen.io/inquisitive/full/WqGJZr). All I want is to add text 'Available' to those dates with no events and date should be other than past dates.

Comment: You can do this potentially, but it's awkward to create, and it's actually not very necessary. It will just clutter up your calendar with lots of words. It should be fairly obvious to the user that any day where they cannot already see an event must therefore be available (it sounds, from your description, like you only allow one event per day?). If there are days where you never accept events, then use the businessHours feature to make them appear unavailable. Or if that's not flexible enough, you could highlight available areas using the Background Events feature.

Comment: This question gets asked quite a lot (there was a nearly identical one a couple of days ago) and the answer is always the same as I've given above.

Comment: Yeah, I have also checked all those but none of them are exactly like it. Yeah, it would have better as you mentioned, but unfortunately, I need to do this with available text instead. Here, in this case, I have let the user to input time as well. So, in this criteria (when (time field is not empty)), I want to show in this manner. Could you suggest any idea, for this? I want to show something like `Available for (time from input field)`.

Comment: @ADyson It might be solved if I could loop those start_date and end date of that month view and add div to every date other than element date by looping this line
`$('.fc-day[data-date="' + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '"]').append("<div class='already-booked'><span>Already Booked <br></span></div>");
`

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56643054/how-do-i-put-an-repeating-event-in-future-and-then-the-title-can-be-changed-once) from two days ago is asking for almost the same thing, for example. Similar things get asked on a regular basis.

Comment: "I need to do this with available text instead"...do you? Why, precisely? And how does attaching a time to the event affect things? It isn't really clear. P.S. What views are you allowing on your calendar? Month, or agenda, or list, or what? That can affect how you might approach a problem like this. I really think you should consider the Background Events approach though, at least. It means you can prepare the data server-side, where it's much easier to calculate what the available slots are, instead of trying to mess with the HTML of fullCalendar..

Comment: Ok, so what would be my best bet to tackle this, I need to show available text / green background for those available date slots and red backgrounds for those booked date. I know I am just complicating the things unnecessarily, but this is the requirement at the moment.

Comment: "red backgrounds for those booked date"...surely for the booked slots you just cover them with an actual event? Or is the problem that the day is not filled until a certain number of events exist, and then you want to turn the whole day red? Maybe you'd be better displaying this is an agenda view,if that's the case. It's a possibility, at least. But if you need it to be visible in the month view as well then fair enough

Comment: Anyway, I think overall [https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/background-events](Background Events) is your best choice. On your server, at the same time you prepare the event data of booked events to send to fullCalendar, you can also prepare data showing which slots/days are still available, and which ones are fully booked...you can then provide these as events with the `rendering: "background"` option set (and a colour) and they will fill in the specified area of the calendar with the given colour. That way you're doing things with fullCalendar's functionality, and you can calculate it easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195357/discussion-between-saroj-shrestha-and-adyson).

Answer (score -1):

I have added text "Available" in days which doesn't contain any events.Please check it : 
Code Pen Link : [Full Calendar](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjMeMG?editors=1010)

```js
var calender; 
var date = new Date();
var start_date = null;
var end_date = null;
var events = [];
var events_dates = [];
function getCalenderEvents(start_date,end_date){
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/z31j5",
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(doc) {
      events = [];
      events_dates = [];
      calender.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
      if(doc.data.length > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<(doc.data.length);i++){
          var startTime1 = new Date((doc.data[i].start).toString()).getTime(), endTime1 = new Date((doc.data[i].end).toString()).getTime();
          while (startTime1 <= endTime1){
            events_dates.push(moment(startTime1).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            startTime1 += 86400000;
          }
          doc.data[i].start = new Date(doc.data[i].start);
          doc.data[i].end = new Date(doc.data[i].end);
          events.push(doc.data[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(events);
      console.log(events_dates);
      var startTime = new Date((start_date).toString()).getTime(), endTime = new Date((end_date).toString()).getTime();
      for(var loopTime = startTime; loopTime <= endTime; loopTime += 86400000){
        let date = moment(loopTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let e = {"title":"Avilable","id":(events.length + 1),"start":new Date(date),"end":new Date(date),'date':date};
        if(events_dates.indexOf(date) < 0){
          events.push(e);
        }
      }
      console.log(events);
      calender.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);
    },  
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        calender = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            viewRender: function (view, element) {
              start_date = moment(view.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
              end_date = moment(view.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
              getCalenderEvents(start_date,end_date);
            }
          
        });


})
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
```

Comment: Although it seems working to some extent I am looking quite different, especially I am looking to treat this available text differently than the event.

Comment: If you want you can change color of events and available text, and please mark answer as right if it helps you.